# How did this question get past the quality filter?

Tags: support

I refer you to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/hanged-samsung-tab-and-restarting). Here, I'll quote it below in case it gets edited.

> Title: hanged samsung tab and restarting
>
> i use a samsung galaxy tab GT-P1000
>
> RECENTLY TWO WEEKS BACK I UPDATED TO JELLY WITH NEW CYNOGEN MODE
>
> MY TAB WAS IN FACT RUNNING SMOOTH
>
> YESTERDAY I DOWNLOADED A THEME FROM GO LAUCHER AS SOON AS I INSTALLED MY TAB AOTMATICALLY RESTARTED BUT NOT SHOWING MAIN SCREEN INSTEAD CYNAGEN MOOD RUNS
>
> AT TIMES MAIN SCREEN COMES AND BEFOR I COULD LOOK ONTO IT AGAIN CYNAGEN MOD COMES AND DISPLAYS ITS ICON
>
> PLZ HELP ME

- There is *no punctuation whatsoever*
- While there is lower-case and upper-case text, there's no mixture. It started out all lower-case and then became all upper-case. (Too tired to press the CapsLock key, I guess)
- Obvious spelling errors
- Concludes with "PLZ HELP ME"

Surely our quality standards filter is better than this?

Comment: Too bad my suggestion to factor in all-caps [was rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121301/154510).  But even besides that, starting with `i` and all the others things you mention are (or were) factors.

Comment: Well, there is only one "i". Wouldn't want to trigger on something that trivial.

Comment: http://pics.blameitonthevoices.com/082009/caps_lock_problem.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How?

Well, it boils down to this: the current quality filter is designed to catch some *really* lazy stuff. If you manage to write multiple paragraphs of things that look sorta like words, you're already way ahead.

On Stack Overflow, I recently raised the threshold questions must pass, and that particular question would've failed... But not because of the caps-heavy *body* but rather because of the short, no caps or punctuation title and lackluster tagging.

Comment: I suggest that having no periods _whatsoever_ (outside of a code block) should be a good indicator of poor quality. I mean, you can't get much lazier than that.